# Write $b$ as a function of $a$, given that $\frac{u^\top a}{v^\top a} = \frac{u^\top S b}{v^\top S b}$ for all nonzero vectors $u,v \in R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, systems-of-equations

Let $a$ and $b$ be non othorgonal vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, and let $S$ be positive-definite matrix such that

$$
\frac{u^\top a}{v^\top a} = \frac{u^\top S b}{v^\top S b},\text{ for all nonzero vectors }u,v \in \mathbb R^n.\tag{1}
$$

> **Question.** *Is it possible to explicit write the vector $b$ as a function of the vector $a$ ?*

Although I'm interested in the general case, a solution to the case where $S$ is a diagonal matrix will be already interesting.

### Example

For example if $S = I_n$ the identity matrix, then evaluating (1) with $u=b$ and $v=(\|b\|/\|a\|)a$ gives

$$
\frac{b^\top a}{\|b\|\|a\|} = \frac{\|b\|^2}{(\|b\|/\|a\|)b^\top a} = \frac{\|b\|\|a\|}{b^\top a},
$$
that is $b^\top a = \|a\|\|b\|$, and so we must have $b=r a$ for some $r>0$.

Or alternatively, decompose $b=b_1 + b_2$, where $b_2^\top b_1 = b_2^\top a = 0$. Then, applying (1) with $u=b_2$ and $v=b_1$ gives
$$
b_2^\top S b_1 + b_2^\top S b_2 = 0.
$$
If $S$ is the identity matrix, then the above equation simplies to $\|b_2\|^2=0$, and so we must have $b=b_1 = ra$, for some $r>0$.

---

### Update (solved!)

I just realized that the problem can be reduced worked examples above. Indeed, let $\widetilde{b} := S b$. Then, (1) becomes

$$
\frac{u^\top a}{v^\top a} = \frac{u^\top \widetilde b}{v^\top \widetilde b}, \text{ for all nonzero vectors }u,v \in \mathbb R^n.
$$
But, we showed above that we must have $\widetilde{b} = ra$ for some $r>0$. We conclude that

> $b=rS^{-1} a$ for some $r>0$.

Comment: Since $Sb=ra$ appears in both the numerator and denominator on the LHS, the $r>0$ restriction is unwarranted.

Answer (score 1):

Taking $S$ to be identity for the moment, the relation can be written as $u^t ab^t v \equiv u^t ba^t v$, that is, $ab^t=ba^t$ must be a symmetric rank-1 matrix which is only possible when $b=ra$ for some $r\neq0$. That's why $a$ and $b$ could not be orthogonal. The final given condition that $S$ is pos. def. is just so that it has an inverse.

Comment: Nice approach (upvoted). Note that my problem is already solved. See update from 1 day ago.